# ITMS-90451:CFBundleIdentifier Collision Error

Tags: macos, qt, app-store

I have to modify the application that was submitted to the 3/24.
As a result of the modified the application tries to re-submit to 4/12, the following error appears in my Application Loader.

[2015-04-12 18:41:21 JST]  ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90451:. "CFBundleIdentifier Collision The Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.LespaceVison.RapidCopy' of 'RapidCopy.app / Contents / Frameworks / QtCore.framework 'is in conflict with the Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier value of' RapidCopy.app '. "

Because I thought I was wrong to modify something, but I tried to re-upload the build that was submitted to the 3/24 to try, same error was displayed.

Please tell me what to do or my mistake about this error.
This is a summary of my environment

Mac OS X 10.10.3
XCode 6.3 with CLI Tools 6.3
Qt 5.4.1

I do not use the Xcode.
QtCreator
make
codesign
productbuild
I have created a pkg for submission using these.

Comment: What Info.plist files does your app bundle contain?

Comment: thx reply. material is here (RapidCopy.app/Info.plist and frameworks... Info.plist)https://lespa.firestorage.com/download/27c27fd18a8c245109bab03d7d4fb69eeadac72d

Comment: I found same trouble. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608264/error-itms-90451-cfbundleidentifier-collision-error but I have to use QtFrameWork....

Comment: I was determined that the problem of this problem "Apple iTunes Connect Server", was to write to Developper forum as well as send a report to Apple.
People who are in trouble with the same problem might be better to send a report to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

This error was resolved!!
I will show how to resolve for those who have the same problem.
In my case, two problem existed.

1. ITMS-90451 Error
   It was caused CFBundleIdentifier that is in the FrameWork.
   CFBundleIdentifier of FrameWork should not be the same as App.
   This is a rule from the old days, but now checks in ItunesConnect recently.
   I was sentenced to change from Apple's support.
   So, you should write the contents other than what has been used in the App to CFBundleIdentifier.
   It was okay if you use as it is what QtFrameWork generated by default in my case.
   Maybe, or content is unique and I think that it does not become a problem.

   2.ITMS-90334 Error
   After I clear problem 1(ITMS-90451), I was suffering from this problem.
   The cause of this problem is in the codesign.
   I had been used to find a sample of QtFrameWork, in the sample when the codesign to FrameWork,
   it was specify BundleID of App with the -i option. This is a mistake.
   mistake example was here.
   codesign -f -s "YOUR APP CERT" -i "YOUR APP BUNDLEID" "YOURAPP".app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework
   answer is here
   codesign -f -s "YOUR APP CERT" "YOURAPP".app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework


   I was called to be any announcement regarding changes to the Apple,
   But they explained would not add.
   Is this information may useful for someone.

   cheer up!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by deleting values from info.plist of pods/dependencies. See detail answer here. : [error itms-90451 "CFBundleIdentifier Collision Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608264/error-itms-90451-cfbundleidentifier-collision-error/29746941#29746941)

Comment: Thank you for answer.
However, I have not used the Cocoapod, not even using Xcode.
QtCreator and make, codesign, it has created a pkg to incorporate productbuild command.
So, it does not become the answer.

Comment: i downloaded your file from this url : https://lespa.firestorage.com/download/27c27fd18a8c245109bab03d7d4fb69eeadac72d

you project actually contains two info.plist files. They both are conflicting see here : http://imgur.com/ozkzkl4

Comment: thx reply.
I am submitted by placing the Info.plist in accordance with Apple's Framework Programming Guide.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html
Therefore, I think this place is thought to be correct.
I tried to delete the CFBundleIdentifier in it and info.plist to remove the Info.plist in the Framework to try. Then, other procedures does not work.
So, I think this issue is a matter different from the problem you have to solve.
Thank you for your opinion.