# error itms-90451 "CFBundleIdentifier Collision Error"

Tags: xcode, upload, collision, cfbundleidentifier

[image]

I uploaded a version of my app – this error pop ups and I dont have any changes from the Google Maps portion of my app. On my first upload, there was no problem.

Answer (score 7):

Just remove the embed frameworks build phase from your extension.

Click on extension in target section -> Build phases -> remove the embed pods frameworks

See attached picture:

[image]

Comment: For me in the year 2020 this phase was called "Embed Frameworks", but removing it still did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is probably Apple's iTunesConnect side of the problem.
see my question:
[ITMS-90451:CFBundleIdentifier Collision Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588606/)

I also encountered the same problem in the submission of the application using the Qt framework.
I have submitted a report in https://bugreport.apple.com/.
Something I will even write if there is a reply from Apple.

Comment: In 4/17 I received from Apple Technical Support. However, the problem did not resolve at all.
I wrote in detail the progress of this topic in Mac DeveloperForum.
Please look at the following URL.
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1127790#1127790

Comment: Add in 4/29 is below.
This error was resolved!!
Please answer refer to my question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588606/

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if iTunes Connect is having a temporary issue. I have the same exact error, now with a different third party library

Comment: I also did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

I Solve the problem. I just deleted the 3rd party framework. Then add it again. I don't why it cause this but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks Signing set to None and Don't Code Sign.

Build Phases - Copy Files - Code Sign On Copy Enabled

Answer (score 0):

This issue is either iTunesConnect issue or Cocoapods.

When you archive and submit the App, you get this “CFBundleIdentifier Collision Error” because iTunesConnect is considering info.plist of one of pod dependency not your Watchkit App or its parent App.

In our case, it was considering Google Maps and Instabug's info.plist file.

**Solution** : 
To solve this issue we deleted all the values of info.plist from our pod dependency. Clean archive and successfully submitted.

GoogleMap iOS SDK contains info.plist on following path : GoogleMapSDK -> Resources -> GoogleMaps.bundle -> info.plist

[image: Google Map info.plist]

**Screenshots of Errors** :

[image: Instabug]

[image: Google Maps]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the 'key/value pair' from your 'pod dependency' please? I'm a bit lost as to what you mean.

Comment: By key/value pair i mean, info.plist of your pod dependency. In Google Map SDK -> Resources -> GoogleMaps.bundle -> info.plist.

Delete values in info.plist of your pod dependency.

Comment: Have also added the screenshot now.

Comment: Thanks! So you essentially submitted an app with an empty Info.plist file inside your pod dependency?

Comment: info.plist under pod dependency is actually useless, Our submitted Watchkit App was approved by Apple Yesterday.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information! Congrats on the approval :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one target in your app and a Framework used in more than one target, you don’t need to embed it in all targets. Just embed it in one target and set the property to "Do not embed" for other targets.
Note that some targets like NetworkExtensions, should not embed some dependencies, therefore the Main target is the preferred target to embed the Framework which caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming so down and you still won't got your issue fixes. :)

Then try to concentrate on CFBundleIdentifier for which "CFBundleIdentifier Collision Error" is showing.

```
Asset validation failed
CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value '**com.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx-iOS**' under the iOS application 'xxxxxx.app'. (ID: 83f747fd-f6f9-4616-b2a0-83e305703ec8)

Asset validation failed
Invalid Bundle. The bundle at '**xxxxx.app/Frameworks/yyyyyyyy.framework**' contains disallowed nested bundles. (ID: 96f9500f-71b3-4d1a-b6a8-bc1b33fba821)
```

This SDK is imported in multiple places i.e xxxxxx.app and xxxxx.app/Frameworks/yyyyyyyy.framework

**Solution**:

Tap on  **yyyyyyyy.framework**

then

Go To General Tab > Frameworks and Library > Tap on the Collision creating library > Change **Embed & Sign** to  "**do not Embed**"