# How to fix Application Loader Error: Invalid Bundle. The bundle ... contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a Swift project with three Swift custom frameworks. The App builds and runs successfully but when I try to upload to iTunes Connect using Application Loader I get the following error for all three frameworks:

ERROR ITMS-90206: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'XXX.app/Frameworks/YYY.framework' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'."

As discussed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25789145/2466193) I have set the 'Embedded Content Contains Swift Code' to NO in the frameworks and YES in the App, but this error persists.

The three Frameworks are all my own (I am seriously considering reworking the project to avoid Frameworks altogether but that is a chore I would like to avoid right now).

I am not using cocoapods.

Any ideas on how to resolve this error?

Comment: Check out this solution: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748933/error-itms-90206-invalid-bundle-contains-disallowed-file-frameworks/35751497](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748933/error-itms-90206-invalid-bundle-contains-disallowed-file-frameworks/35751497)

Comment: Thanks @Jake, yes I tried that one too - no luck I am afraid, error still persists.

Comment: See my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608264/error-itms-90451-cfbundleidentifier-collision-error/40396491#40396491

Answer (score 4):

The key to solving this for me was, in addition to `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO`, also setting `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT=NO` in build settings for all targets *except* the main app target.  Had to clear out derived data, but after that all was well.

[image]

Comment: Deprecated since Xcode 8.3. See @Mesird 's answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In (SE-0133) of [the Xcode 8.3 Release note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html), there's a description about `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` setting:

> The new build setting ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES replaces the EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT setting, which has been deprecated. This new setting indicates that Xcode should always embed Swift standard libraries in a target for which it has been set, whether or not the target contains Swift code. A typical scenario for using this setting is when a target directly uses or embeds another product that contains Swift code. (26158130)

which means `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` has replaced `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT`, thus you need to change the former one(`ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`) to `NO` in the extension target.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not a good answer, but it is what I did to resolve it:

I created a new project and copied in all my files - in a flat structure without Frameworks, editing just to remove the relevant import statements. It now uploads fine. So it is the Framework structure that is the root of the problem. Not sure if the idea of Swift embedded custom libraries is just broken or I was doing something wrong so still looking for better answers...